# Create rect element with two-sided radius only

Tags: html, css, svg, rect

I don't know how to make rect element with 2-sided radius only, please find the exhibit:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="400" height="180">
  <rect x="50" y="20" rx="1"  ry="50" width="30" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5">
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `path` element instead?

Comment: @Harry i am using extJS sir

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what is supposed to mean. Is using a `path` element not possible with it? Anyway, if you can't use it, leave it :)